# Displaying nested comments in MVC 3 blog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am making a Blog using MVC 3, Razor and Entity Framework. I am now working on the **Comment** section.

I am using the following table for comments.

[image: My Comment table]

Here I am using the 'CommentParent' column and setting it a value of an another 'CommentID' if a user is **replying** to a comment, else I have set a value of null.

### Problem

I am using the following code to display comments,

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{
    <div>
        @comment.CommentContent
    </div>
    <br />
}
```

I am not sure how to display the "replyTo" comments as shown in the image below...
[image]
Please can anyone guide me as how this can be done...

Comment: i would strart by somehof grouping the comments

Comment: I believe that the easiest way requires a small change at your model: `Comment` should have a list of comments, such as `Replies`. This way, you could recursively iterate at this list, creating the markup.

Comment: BTW: it would be more semantic to display each comment inside a `<p>`, not inside a `<div>`.

Comment: you need a tree traversing algorithm.i am trying to write one for you.

Comment: I have made same thing as your in my past. I can suggest you a thing that fetch all data you need and put children to parent after fetching and remove them from the list. this way you can easily loop in Views and easily fetch them from Database.

Comment: I am tring @AndreCalil solution and seems to be getting to it... :)

Comment: @Yasser Don't forget to share the solution =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First You will have to change your Model Class, Lets suppose your model class is :

```
public class CommentsModel
{
     Public Int64 CommentId {get;set;}
     ....
     ....
     //Introduce a new property in it as:
     Public CommentsModel[] ChildComments {get;set;}
}
```

This new property will hold the child comments of a specific comment up to N Level. Than in your View you can do it like:

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{
    <div>
    @comment.CommentContent
    </div>
    <br />
    @if(comment.ChildComments.Length > 0)
    {
        // Display Level 1 Comments and so on and so far
    }
}
```

You can manage the lookout of comments by using Css Class on Divs.

Comment: I am wondering how this solution worked.  I have introduced  the property but nesting is not working  ChildComments  return null in view as well. Which part  of the magic am I missing?

Comment: Are you populating the ChildComments from controller?

Comment: Yes I realised that  after careful consideration but I am struggling to display the  sub levels  iteration to show level 1 , 2 , 3....

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 private void CreateComments(int ? postId, int ? cid)
      {          
        int? id = cid;                
        var replies = new List<Comment>();
        if (postId.HasValue())
        {
              var BlogPost = context.Posts.Single(p=>p.Id == postId.Value);
              replies = BlogPost.Comments.Where(c=>c.CommentParent == null);  
        }
        else
        {
            replies = context.Comments.Where(c=>c.CommentParent == id);         
        }  

        int level = 0;
        Comment tmp = new Comment();
        foreach (Comment reply in replies)
            {     
                tmp = reply;
                while(tmp.CommentParent != null){
                      level++;
                      tmp = context.Comments.Single(c=>c.Id == tmp.CommentParent);
                }
                //logic for creating your html tag 
                //you can use "level" to leave appropriate indent back to your comment.
                CreateComments(null,reply.id);
            }   
     }
```

**Edit:**

you can even determine your current level like i did inside foreach loop.

i hope this could help.